# awk apply changes if values are not there in file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file say file1 with the following contents

```
cat file1
test
test1
```

I am appending the word raspberry to multiple files here test and test1 and it works fine.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' "$i" > "$i.tmp" &&
  mv "$i.tmp" "$i"
done < file1
```

The issue is if I run the script 10 times, it appends the word raspberry 10 times.

Is there any way we can check the word raspberry is already there and if its not there apply the change else simply exit?

Comment: `/raspberry/ {next}`?

Comment: Let's see some data and th expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep`, to list found matches, and then `wc` to count the number of lines that grep returns.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r i; do
    #If grep returns zero lines, raspberry was not found:
    if [[ $(echo $i | grep -c raspberry) -eq 0 ]]
    then
        awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' "$i" > "$i.tmp" &&
        mv "$i.tmp" "$i"
    fi
done < file1
```

Comment: `$(cat $i | grep "raspberry" | wc -l) -eq 0` can be rewritten as `$(grep -c raspberry "$i") -eq 0` to take care of useless use of `cat` and quoting of `$i` and eliminating `wc -l`.

Comment: So it can. Bad habits die hard, I guess. I'll edit the answer to add in your change. Quick question, though; shouldn't the string `raspberry` be quoted as a "best practices" sort of thing?

Comment: It need not be -- it is a shell literal and has no whitespace or special characters.

Comment: Good to know. I noticed something while testing the change with the loop as a whole, though. I wasn't paying complete attention, and thought it was a loop to read one file at a time, but it's actually a loop to read a file one line at a time. As such, when i tried your code, grep just complains that each line isn't a valid file location (Because $i contains an arbitrary string, not a filename). In this case, the best solution would be `$(echo $i | grep -c raspberry) -eq 0`, right?

Comment: I hadn't looked at the question.  If `$i` is a string, then we don't need `grep` at all.  The condition could be written as `if ! [[ "$i" == *raspberry* ]]; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  awk '/\[/{f=/groups/} f && !/raspberry/{if (NF) $0=$0",raspberry"} 1' "$i" > "$i.tmp" &&
  mv "$i.tmp" "$i"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
   # reset per file
   FNR == 1 { a = 0; Fs[FILENAME]++ }
   # define state of a at [ occurence
   /^\[/ { a = ( $0 ~ /\[groups/) ? 1 : 0 }

   # modify the line if ...
   a && /=/ && $0 !~ /raspeberry/ && $0 !~ /\[groups/ { $0 = $0 ",raspberry"}
   # output the result to tmp file (per filename)
   { print > ( FILEMANE ".tmp") }

   # mv all tmp to original name
   END { for ( F in Fs ) system ( "mv " F ".tmp " F ) }
   ' $( cat file1 )
```

- done in 1 awk call (that call the mv inside as sub shell, this part could be optimized in shell)
- source is a cat of the file1 instead of a loop
- treat each file with a reset at start of file `FNR == 1`
- Assuming that `[group` could occur with a `=` on same line (if not, `a && /=/ && $0 !~ /raspeberry/ && $0 ~ /\[groups/` could be simplified
- i  don't put any check to only mv modified file (not part of the request) but it's a good advice to.